# How to achieve columns for tableview cells like in iPhone Contacts App - Add New Contact View?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Please refer to the screenshot below

[image]

I am Assuming the "Add new contact" screen in iPhone contacts app had a UITableView. 
For adding phone numbers or email or home page, they have nicely formatted columns within the rows.
How can I achieve this, since UITableView inherently does not support columns? 
Are these just custom UITableViewCell implemented on scroll view?
The mystery is killing me ... please help :)

Thanks,
Dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that they are a couple of UITableView's all positioned on a UIScrollView. The edit button on top of the page, will probably trigger the edit mode on all UITableView's in this view.

If that "Add Photo" button wasn't there, you could solve this all with 1 UITableView by the way.

Comment: UITableView itself is a subclass of UIScrollView. I doubt if they would use a scroll view within a scroll view since there are known problems of doing that. Also if they are using multiple table view side by side (which is what I am inferring from what you are trying to say) how do they get all the scrolling in sync and also how doe the cornered edges line up so nicely giving the "column" effect? Does that make sense?

Comment: Well unless they are using some kind of control not open to us. I guess the UIScrollView in UIScrollView would be the best bet. I used it myself a couple of times (UITableView in an UIScrollView) and there is nog real issue using that. As long as only one of the two is really scrollable. The column effect can easily be created by just drawing a vertical line on a UITableView cell and place 2 UILabels on it.

Comment: The vertical line would be drawn using core animation or something? Just curious!